# Min/Max Facet slider not working

Tags: 7, search

I am working on Search API. I am using Search API module, Facet API, Search API ranges, Pretty Paths modules to add facet filters.

All the filters working fine like select list, checkbox but Min/Max slider not working. When I am moving the slider, it gives 0 results to me.

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. Pretty paths module creates the problem for this. I disables the Pretty Path module and flush the cache.

Now Min/Max slider working fine.